# Build failed after updating tools for Android L

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop

I cannot build my project after updating the tools.  I get this error in Android Studio.

> /build/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/21.0.0-rc1/AndroidManifest.xml:3] Failed to parse : must be an integer number or codename.

Any ideas?

This manifest is from the support library I think.  I also have another for my project which is `min=14 target=19`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.support.v4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="L"
        android:targetSdkVersion="L" />

    <application />

</manifest>
```

> gradle classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'

Comment: If minSdk=targetSdk, it would run **only on the latest OS**. Which will be on the wild by **next fall**.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your app/build.gradle file, change
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'`
to
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'`

The '+' means that it will look for the newest version of the dependency. If you download the L preview, the latest version will be the support library for L - which isn't going to work for a project whose target is API 19.

Comment: What's the reason for the explicit version number?

Comment: By default it will use the newest version... which is the current L release

Comment: Please note, the latest version of Android support library for non-Android-L version is `20.0.0`, so, try to use this line of code: `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'`

Comment: I have multiple and transitive dependencies, which end up resolving to version 21.0.0-rc1 even though I applied this change to some modules. Is there a way to override this globally for whole android application?

Comment: Also, if you're using it, you have to replace `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'` with `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'` for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Did you update your build.gradle file to reflect these changes?

```
compileSdkVersion is set to 'android-L'
minSdkVersion is set to 'L'
targetSdkVersion is set to 'L'
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

Comment: no but, my project is min=14 target=19 I don't need L for now at least. also I'm using gradle 0.9.+

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me and I was able to build the app.

```
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'){
    force = true
}
```