# Failed to parse <uses-sdk minSdkVersion='L'>: must be an integer number or codename

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i have a problem with Android Studio after install the sdk module to implement the push notification. This is my GRADLE file:

```
    apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+') {
        force = true
    }
    compile('com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'){
        force = true
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/circularimageview-26adf57db519d748c8cc585d9d20ca8e.jar')
    compile files('libs/circularimageview.jar')
    compile files('libs/pdfbox-app-1.8.6.jar')
    compile 'com.joanzapata.pdfview:android-pdfview:1.0.+@aar'
    compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+") {
        force = true
    }

}
```

When I build the project I have this error:

```
Failed to parse <uses-sdk minSdkVersion='L'>: must be an integer number or codename.
```

If I click on error, Android studio open an android manifest that i can't modify. How can I solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build failed after updating tools for Android L](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437950/build-failed-after-updating-tools-for-android-l)

Comment: Change this line compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+') to compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0')